# Get my second y-axis in charts.js to always display the 100% tick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, chart.js, recharts

I have a scatter chart using recharts that looks like the following:

[image: 1]

The right-y-axis represents the percentage and it is displaying the correct values as I intended. However, I'd like to adjust it so that the 100% is always displayed. Is this possible?

To build what I currently have, I basically have two nearly-identical datasets, the difference is that one of them is hidden and I changed the ticks callback to display the percentage based on the maximum y values in the points.

Here's my dataset config:

```
datasets: [
  {
    label,
    data: data
      ? Array.from({ length: data.x.values.length || 0 }, (_, i) => ({
          x: data.x.values[i],
          y: data.y.values[i],
        }))
      : [],
    backgroundColor: color,
    borderColor: color,
    pointRadius: 1.2,
    fill: false,
  },
  {
    data: data
      ? Array.from({ length: data.x.values.length || 0 }, (_, i) => ({
          x: data.x.values[i],
          y: data.y.values[i],
        }))
      : [],
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    pointRadius: 0,
    fill: false,
    yAxisID: 'y1',
  },
],
```

And here's my scales config:

```
scales: {
  x: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: data?.x.title || '',
    },
    ticks: {
      callback: formatPlotTicks,
    },
  },
  y: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: data?.y.title || '',
    },
    type: 'linear',
    display: true,
    position: 'left',
    ticks: {
      callback: formatPlotTicks,
    },
  },
  y1: {
    type: 'linear',
    display: true,
    position: 'right',
    ticks: {
      callback: (value) => {
        const percentageValue = ((value as number) / maxYValue) * 100;
        if (percentageValue > 100.5) {
          return '';
        }
        return `${percentageValue.toFixed(0)}%`;
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Have you tried to set min and max to the axis? Maybe 0 as min and 100 as max?

Comment: @user2057925 That won't work because I'm mirroring the y-axis values into the y1-axis and then on the ticks' callback I re-label the ticks. If I set max to 100, it'll display only the values where in the y-axis is lower than 100 (but in percentage) which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, but if you want that the percentage scale will be reflecting the real percentage of the dataset which is shown using the other scale, the data scale should have the max option set to the real max value of the dataset otherwise the 100% is located to the max of the dataset (as is in the picture) but not to end of the chart. I cannot understand how the chart will look like. The 100% of the mirror scale is correctly calculated but not showed because the scale calculates automatically the min/max, if not set.

Comment: @user2057925 indeed, but I think the ideal would be adjust both axis to make sure the max y value is always displayed. That way it'll fix the percentage as well, isn't it? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I could simply add max: maxYValue, but then the top tick will always be the max, which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think you don't have many other options, as far as I know. The Y axis should set the max value (max: maxYValue) and then, accordingly you have Y1 correctly aligned with percentage. If you don't want to the have the top tick is always the max, the Y1 axis will be always as you described in the original question, because the 100% is located where the max value is (on Y axis).

Comment: @user2057925 Hmmm, is it possible to maybe detect the position of the highest y value point related to the canvas? That way I could add the percentage axis separately.

Comment: yes, it is but then? You cannot use in the axis. But let me ask you: is it acceptable for you to have the Y1 axis where 100% is shown even if is not on top? If yes, the dataset linked to Y1 could be changed, having the percentage instead of values.

Comment: @user2057925 that's exacly what I want. the 100% should not be on top, it should be aligned to the point that maps the highest y value.

Comment: @user2057925 maybe it's possible by adjusting the stepSize?

Comment: uhmm... why don't use a line annotation (with a label) where there is max value and leave the axis as is?

Comment: @user2057925 how would that work? And also, is it possible to have it show that it represents 100%?

Comment: something like that: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/XWxRPGy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adjusting the options and scales like this:

Dataset:

```
datasets: [
  {
    label,
    data: data
      ? Array.from({ length: data.x.values.length || 0 }, (_, i) => ({
          x: data.x.values[i],
          y: data.y.values[i],
        }))
      : [],
    backgroundColor: color,
    borderColor: color,
    pointRadius: 1.2,
    fill: false,
  },
  {
    data: data
      ? Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, i) => ({
          x:
            i === 0
              ? 0
              : data?.x.values[i * 20 - 1] ||
                data?.x.values[(data?.x.values.length || 0) - 1],
          y: i === 6 ? Kpercent : i * 20,
        }))
      : [],
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    pointRadius: 1.2,
    fill: false,
    yAxisID: 'y1',
  },
],
```

Options:

```
scales: {
  x: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: data?.x.title || '',
    },
    ticks: {
      callback: formatPlotTicks,
    },
  },
  y: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: data?.y.title || '',
    },
    type: 'linear',
    display: true,
    position: 'left',
    ticks: {
      callback: formatPlotTicks,
    },
  },
  y1: {
    type: 'linear',
    display: true,
    position: 'right',
    min: 0,
    max: Kpercent,
    afterBuildTicks: (scaleInstance) => {
      scaleInstance.ticks.pop();
      scaleInstance.ticks.push({ value: 100 });
    },
    ticks: {
      stepSize: 20,
      callback: (value) => `${value}%`,
    },
    grid: {
      drawOnChartArea: false,
    },
  },
},
```